# Does it pay to use weak (or soft, etc.) reference as the parent reference in a tree?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

For GC efficiencies sake - that is making the periodic GC sweep stalls shorter and/or less frequent for a given heap size, does it pay in a parent child tree to use weak references in children for referencing their parents to prevent GC reference loops? Or is the difference negligible?

to clarify I mean use a weak reference *instead* of a strong reference.  It can be assumed I need to access the parent from the child and the children from the parent, as access is needed outside of traversals.

Comment: What did you try to find out so far?

Comment: well in a reference counted system you can't have loops and am converting to java :) have looked at many docs but no mention of whether the structure of the object handle graph does or does not affect GC performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have issues with reference loops, so if that is your only concern then, no, you don't need to use Weak/Soft references for parent references.

Comment: if it is true that there is no difference in GC performance then no reason not to use a strong reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in JVM internals but it seems to be even worse. Soft/Weak links come into play when object is not reachable through the strong links. Outgoing links should not affect object's eligibility for the garbage collection. Link to the parent is outgoing. Consider two situations:

- Child is eligible for garbage collection and ancestors are eligible
  too. I would expect that all the tree is eligible for the garbage
  collection.
- Child is not eligible for garbage collection and there
  are no strong links to the ancestors. If ancestors are reachable only
  throught the weak links then they should be GCed. Can this affect
  correctness of the program?

When speaking about performance writing GC-free programs gives much more predictability than playing with weaker reference types. Writing GC-free is a preferrable way to deal with garbage collection (iff it is the reason of your performance problems)

For more details you can refer for example to the [Memory Management in the Java Hotspot Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf) whitepaper.

Comment: Obviously the parents won't get GC'ed. I think that he assumes that if there is a soft-link the GC won't follow it to determine which objects are reachable. (An object reachable only by a weak reference doesn't need to be saved any way.)

Comment: @aioobe, could you please elaborate why? I used to think that if some object has no strong references then it should be GCed. F.i. `WeakReference` documentation says: `Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed`. (Object -> WeakReference -> Eligible for GC)

Comment: Right. So does the GC need to follow weak references? (No, since whatever it finds can still be considered "unreachable".) Thus the hypothesis is, I assume, that a weak reference will not even be traversed.

Comment: right - my concern is there are a lot of loops in the handle graph that the GC sweep algoryhm would be more expensive and reduce performance.  If this is not true then I see no reason not to place looping references in from children to parents.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon how you use your tree.

If you are not requiring the parent elements of a tree and are not referencing the parents from other parts of your application, then it may pay to use some sort of weak reference from the child to the parent.  Keep in mind that you will be allowing your parent elements to be arbitrarily garbage collected.  Also, your tree would have to be substantially large to see any difference in periodic GC.

Of course, if you do not require the parent elements to be referenced consistently, I would consider not keeping a parent parameter at all.  This would make your implementation a bit more consistent and less complex.